# Why a two-lever valve spring compressor?

Tags: tools, valve

I just purchased a valve spring compressor that has a lever on both ends, similar to this one:

[image: Two-lever valve spring compressor]

What is not clear to me is the advantage of having this two-lever setup.

What does it have over the more common single-lever design like this one?

[image: Single-lever valve spring compressor]

Comment: @CharlieRB yes, especially if you push the cap down and it goes deep into the housing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't appear to have a special purpose other than convenience. According to the [Draper Tools Website](http://www.drapertools.com/product/02713/Expert-55-175mm-Universal-Valve-Spring-Compressor);

> Suitable for use on most engines due to double-ended valve cup. Unique
>   double action lever cams action provide choice of operation either
>   above or below valve.